# Share the same gRPC server streaming iterator with many clients

Tags: python, streaming, grpc

We are writing an application that leverage gRPC. We implemented a bunch of Unary RPCs that clients can regularly call, getting the expected response.

Also, we have a streaming (from server to client) dedicated to continuously streams some information that are shared across all the clients (let's say some hardware local sensors information – such as room temperatures).

The Python `StatusStreaming` function now returns the streaming iterator and it loops constantly to stream data to the clients.

The problem is that **it returns a new iterator for every client**; being it  updated every 100ms, that makes our system not able to serve more then a dozen clients before reaching full load. Also, it doesn't make sense to use a separate cycle for every clients, as we need to send the same exact content to all the clients.

Is it actually possible **to broadcast the same streaming content to many clients** without having different connection/channel for each of them?

#### Some background

We use `gRPC-web` to implement the RPCs on browsers clients, so bidi streaming is not possible (I don't have an idea how to use it anyhow, but it wouldn't be availble).

Versions uses are those tied to grpc-web (grpc version grpc @ d8772cf and protobuf at 3.7.0).

Our server, is limited in resources, as we are on a small embedded server (1 core, 1gb ram).

**Here is the streamer**

```py
# Inside a method of the service class here
def _Status(self):
    system_controller = self._system_status()
    return protos.Stream(temperature_controller)

# Real Python streaming method
def Status(self, request, context):
    def streaming_iterator():
       while(context.is_active()):
           time.sleep(0.5)
           yield self._Status()
       return streaming_iterator()
```

A new connection is created (and also the dedicated streaming channel) for every client and so a new `while` cycle spawns generating data to send. This behaviour isn't needed, because the same information can be actually shared across all the clients in **broadcasting** fashion.